# Find max value for each year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question that is asking:

-List the max sales for each year?

I think I have the starter query but I can't figure out how to get all the years in my answer:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(stockdate,'YYYY') AS year, sales
FROM sample_newbooks
WHERE sales = (SELECT MAX(sales) FROM sample_newbooks);
```

This query gives me the year with the max sales.  I need max sales for EACH year.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by` and `max` if all you need is year and max sales of the year.

```
select 
    to_char(stockdate, 'yyyy') year,
    max(sales) sales
from sample_newbooks
group by to_char(stockdate, 'yyyy')
```

If you need rows with all the columns with max sales for the year, you can use window function row_number:

```
select
    *
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over (partition by to_char(stockdate, 'yyyy') order by sales desc) rn
    from sample_newbooks t
) t where rn = 1;
```

If you want to get the rows with ties on sales, use `rank`:

```
select
    *
from (
    select
        t.*,
        rank() over (partition by to_char(stockdate, 'yyyy') order by sales desc) rn
    from sample_newbooks t
) t where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Do **not** use `to_char` for parsing out a year of a date. Use `extract(year from stockdate)` instead!